# Could not load the Inf file XXX.inf due to Incorrect driver version in version section of the inf

Tags: driver, code-signing-certificate, inf

I'm trying to send my driver to Microsoft Partner Center to get an attestation signing for kernel driver at https://partner.microsoft.com/pt-br/dashboard/hardware/ but when I submit my .cab file Microsoft return this error: "Could not load the Inf file XXX.inf due to Incorrect driver version in version section of the inf".

1. I bought an Code Signing EV certificate.
2. I created my account in Microsoft Partner Center.
3. I signed my drivers XXX.sys (32 and 64 bits) with my Code Signing non-EV certificate.
4. I created manually the .inf file (see below)
5. I tested my .INF file with InfVerif tool.
6. I created my Driver.cat with Inf2cat tool
7. I signed my .cat file with my Code Signing non-EV certificate.
8. I mounted a .cab with MakeCab tool with .inf, .cat, .sys (32 bits) and .sys (64 bits)
9. I signed my .cab file with my Code Signing EV certificate.
10. I sent the generated cab to Microsoft Partner Center in Hardware -> Driver section.
11. A received the error above

I just tried to Google this error and search in Microsoft Hardware Dev Center, but I wasn't successful.

This is my .inf file:

```
; XXX.inf
;
; Installation inf for the XXX.
; Copyright (c) 2019 YYY. All rights reserved.
;

[Version]
Signature = "$WINDOWS NT$"
Class = HSM
ClassGuid = {d546500a-2aeb-45f6-9482-f4b1799c3177}
Provider = %Company%
DriverVer = %Version%
CatalogFile = XXX.cat

[Manufacturer]
%Company% = XXX, NTx86, NTamd64

[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir = 12
XXX.NTx86.CopyFiles = 12
XXX.NTamd64.CopyFiles = 12

; Windows 2000 and XP
[XXX]
%ServiceDesc% = XXX.NTx86.ndi

; Windows Vista or later
[XXX.NTx86]
%ServiceDesc% = XXX.NTx86.ndi

[XXX.NTamd64]
%ServiceDesc% = XXX.NTamd64.ndi

; Installation
[XXX.NTx86.ndi]
CopyFiles = XXX.NTx86.CopyFiles

[XXX.NTx86.ndi.Services]
AddService = %ServiceName%,,XXX.NTx86.Service

[XXX.NTx86.Service]
DisplayName = %ServiceName%
Description = %ServiceDesc%
ServiceBinary = %12%\XXX_32.sys
ServiceType = 2 ; SERVICE_FILE_SYSTEM_DRIVER
StartType = 1 ; SERVICE_SYSTEM_START
ErrorControl = 1 ; SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL
LoadOrderGroup = "File System"

[XXX.NTx86.CopyFiles]
XXX_32.sys

[XXX.NTamd64.ndi]
CopyFiles = XXX.NTamd64.CopyFiles

[XXX.NTamd64.ndi.Services]
AddService = %ServiceName%,,XXX.NTamd64.Service

[XXX.NTamd64.Service]
DisplayName = %ServiceName%
Description = %ServiceDesc%
ServiceBinary = %12%\XXX_64.sys
ServiceType = 2 ; SERVICE_FILE_SYSTEM_DRIVER
StartType = 1 ; SERVICE_SYSTEM_START
ErrorControl = 1 ; SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL
LoadOrderGroup = "File System"

[XXX.NTamd64.CopyFiles]
XXX_64.sys

[SourceDisksNames]
1 = %Disk1%

[SourceDisksFiles]
XXX_32.sys = 1
XXX_64.sys = 1

[Strings]
Company = "YYY"
Version = 09/05/2019,1.0.0.17
Disk1 = "XXX Driver Installation Disk #1"
ServiceDesc = "XXX Driver for File System"
ServiceName = "XXX Driver"
```

I expected my drivers to be signed by Microsoft without the error described.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.
It was a syntax error that was not being performed by the InfVerif tool.

Try using a variable to get summer information, but the correct era use two:

```
...
[Version]
...
DriverVer = %Date%,%Version%
...
[Strings]
...
Date = 09/05/2019
Version = 1.0.0.17
...
```